# NSArray not deallocating in ARC Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, matrix, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to write a command line application in Objective-C for a university project. The project needs matrix manipulation so I have written a class to handle all the matrix methods (Addition and multiplication and such). My matrix methods look like this:

```
- (NSArray *)sumMatrices:(NSArray *)matrices
{
    NSMutableArray *sum = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSInteger cols = [matrices[0][0] count];
    NSInteger rows = [matrices[0] count];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        NSMutableArray *row = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

            CGFloat value = 0.0;

            for (NSArray *array in matrices) {
                value += [array[i][j] doubleValue];
            }

            [row addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:value]];

        }

        [sum addObject:[row copy]];
        row = nil;

    }

    return [sum copy];

}
```

However theres is a massive problem with this programme, I having used objective-c for iOS expect ARC to handle all my memory allocation and deallocation without a problem, however in this case the `NSMutableArray` 'sum' is never being deallocated, and because this method is being called in a loop which runs 10's of thousands of times (Modelling a double pendulum using RK4) the memory usage builds up and makes the program extremely slow.

Is there any reason this `NSMutableArray` isn't being deallocated once this method has returned?

Comment: You have written in for loop so how many times it execute that much time value will added in your array

Comment: Which array are you thinking is not being deallocated? The original `sum` or the copy you are returning? What is holding onto the return value?

Comment: It looks like an extremely inefficient way of doing what you want.  Dealing with `NSNumber` objects is a pain, so I would say use `malloc()`d 2-dimensional array of `float`s.  It will be *way* quicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is less about this code and more about the code surrounding it. Let's assume for a moment that your code around it looks like this:

```
NSArray *matricies; //Declared somewhere else;
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i < [matricies count] - 1; i++) {
    for (int j=i+1; j < [matricies count]; i++) {
        NSArray *sum = [self sumMatrices:@[matricies[i], matricies[j]]];
        [results addObject:sum];
    }
}
```

The actual operations that I'm performing are not particularly relevant to this example. The code pattern is. You'll notice I'm using a nested "tight" loop. Control never returns to the run loop until AFTER all calculations are complete. Without ARC, your memory would be freed as soon as the last `release` was performed, excluding autoreleased objects. With ARC, your memory is not freed until control is returned to the runloop, much the same way autoreleased objects used to. As a result, your code will appear to leak, until processing is complete and the system decides it should release your memory. If the CPU is perpetually under a heavy load, it may not clean up memory until it absolutely has to.

There are a few cleaver ways to use `@autoreleasepool` to help in this case, but that will make your code significantly slower. Additionally, Objective C is a fairly slow language for objects and method calls. If you are using this code heavily, you should convert it into C or C++ and manage the memory yourself.

Comment: I think I'll take your advice and change it to use C++, it seems this is way more of a pain in the arse than it's worth...

Answer (score 0):

without going into much detail you can try to use autoreleasepool

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/memorymgmt/articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

i would use copy if i want to preserve an array which gets modified but in your case do you really need it ?

Comment: Did you tried it in the for-loop? (right after the for- command)

Comment: Yeah no luck putting anything in an autorelease block... :/ Even if I wrap the main method in main.m in an autorelease block it still builds up

Comment: why do you use copy ?

Comment: It's left over from an attempt I made to allow me to set sum to nil before returning. Didn't work in the end. Removing it won't (and doesn't) make a difference